# Notification when left menu bar is closed?

Tags: javascript

How to get a notification via Javascript when the left menu bar has been collapsed ?

I was looking everywhere in the net but there is zero out there...
thanks!

update: somebody asked what the left menu bar in Wordpress is : the left menu bar is on the left side. the last button is 'collapse menu'. all i need is a notification when the user changed the collapse state.

Comment: What left menu bar? Please edit the question to include all relevant details.

Comment: i updated for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How to get a notification via Javascript when the left menu bar has been collapsed ?
```

If you are taking about the admin menu bar and you want to get a notification when the that is closed and expanded, then watch thoroughly that, when admin menu bar is collapsed, a `folded` class is added to the body. You can get any notification according to that.